# Wordpress: How to show posts from a specific category via the loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a menu bar with different topics (technology, food, etc.) When I click on one of those, I would like to display all posts that have that specific topic assigned. Everything I have found online shows me how to do this by specifying the topic using an ID. However, I do not want to "hard code" it, but rather run a function that gets the name of the page, and then displays posts that correspond to that category. So essentially, instead of having cat=1 in my query argument, I would like to enter code that gets the title of the page, as the title of the page equals the category I want to show. I have posted the first part of my code below. My loop works fine other than that and displays the content how I want it to. I just need to figure out how to dynamically fetch the page title and assign that as the category value. Thank you for any help

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to use Custom template:**

The idea can be. You need to use page(in the menu) same as category slug.

Then get page slug using:

`<?php 
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
?>`

Complete code for template:

```
global $post;
$post_slug=$post->post_name;

 $args = array( 'category_name' => $post_slug );
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
// no posts found
}
```

OR you can add those categories into menu from Appearance>>Menus and then

1. `category.php`
   or
2. `archive.php`

will show your all posts of specific category just you need to modify to fit your requirements. For more: https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Answer (score 0):

I guess those topics on menu are links to category (You can added categories to menu). If yes then having `category.php` template file in your them will automatically list all the post from category and also set the page title to category